# How do I determine what an alternative whitespace character is in my file

Tags: vim, text, character-encoding

In my web application, I process data feeds and I split words by whitespaces (and other key tokens) before indexing the words.

One of my files has a strange whitespace character and my list of key tokens does not catch it, meaning I cannot correctly process that part of the file.

If I look at the file in vi, the text in question looks like this:

`"SKS Shockboard Front QR Mudguard"`

The final space, however, is not a regular whitespace, which I can see by running `:%s/\ /_/g`. The text becomes:

`"SKS_Shockboard_Front_QR Mudguard"`

I need to determine what that final whitespace character is. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a mac, you can use the `xxd` tool to see the hex representation (i.e., encoding) of each character:

```
/usr/bin/xxd file.txt
```

Then find the hex representation in the spot where the non-space whitespace is and look it up at unicode.org.

(Also, if you need to do this sort of thing often and want to stay within vim, you might look for the "HexMode" code, or just use xxd directly as explained here:  http://www.kevssite.com/2009/04/21/using-vi-as-a-hex-editor/.)

Comment: Yes that is what I needed to do. I found a tool for this: http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/

The character was as follows:`SKS Shockboard Front QR¬†Mudguard1` with the HEX: `22 53 4B 53 20 53 68 6F 63 6B 62 6F 61 72 64 20 46 72 6F 6E 74 20 51 52 C2 A0 4D 75 64 67 75 61 72 64 22`

Comment: (The offending characters are C2 A0, which is a NO BREAK SPACE.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use vim you can move the cursor onto the character in question and press `ga` to show the ascii value of the character.

Help for `ga` is copied below.

```
:as[cii]        or                                      ga :as :ascii
ga                      Print the ascii value of the character under the
                        cursor in decimal, hexadecimal and octal.  For
                        example, when the cursor is on a 'R':
                                <R>  82,  Hex 52,  Octal 122
                        When the character is a non-standard ASCII character,
                        but printable according to the 'isprint' option, the
                        non-printable version is also given.  When the
                        character is larger than 127, the <M-x> form is also
                        printed.  For example:
                                <~A>  <M-^A>  129,  Hex 81,  Octal 201
                                <p>  <|~>  <M-~>  254,  Hex fe,  Octal 376
                        (where <p> is a special character)
                        The <Nul> character in a file is stored internally as
                        <NL>, but it will be shown as:
                                <^@>  0,  Hex 00,  Octal 000
                        If the character has composing characters these are
                        also shown.  The value of 'maxcombine' doesn't matter.
                        Mnemonic: Get Ascii value.  {not in Vi}
```